# Can multitasking gestures in iPad 2 be disabled for specific apps?

Tags: ios, ipad

As much as I like multitasking gestures , they are creating problems in certain games where we use multiple fingers like Fruit Ninja , can these be disabled for specific apps/games on my iPad 2?

Answer (score 1):

Currently and without jailbreak no and I doubt Apple will ever introduce this option as it would be only useful to a few people. It's all or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of a repeat "no" answer, I would like say add to the two existing replies and clarify that that I have never come across any setting that has been anything other than system wide, it's either on, or it is off, whether it's silent mode for everyone bar your mom, or send read replies to everyone except your dad etc.  It's just how it works, and it's a conscious decision to enable consistency and ease of use more than a limitation.

Comment: Notifications can be configured on a per app basis.

Comment: Aha!  Yes, a good point, although the exception I think :)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, no, at least with the official software.